# Randomize List<string> without duplicates

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have a

```
List<string> notizen = new List<string>();
```

I want to choose a random entry from it but this entry should not be repeated until all entries of notizen have been shown.

Application looks like this:

String is on the screen, you tap on it, another text is on the screen. I want to randomly go through the notizen list without having double entries until all entries have been shown, then it starts with a new randomized version of notizen.

notizen could be randomized itself, no temporary list necessary. But I found LINQ to not exist in monodroid.

Comment: Look up the concept of shuffling.

Comment: This is likely a duplicate question. Answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shuffle your List using [Fisher–Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) algorithm in `O(n)`; once your iterator equals n, perform a second shuffle and so on.

The pseudocode for it, as presented in wikipedia, is :

```
To shuffle an array a of n elements (indices 0..n-1):
  for i from n − 1 downto 1 do
   j ← random integer with 0 ≤ j ≤ i
   exchange a[j] and a[i]
```

You could even write an extension method for that, something like :

```
    public static Random rand = new Random();

    public static List<T> Shuffle<T>(this List<T> original)
    {
        List<T> lst = new List<T>(original);
        for (int i = lst.Count - 1; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            int j = rand.Next(0, i + 1);
            T tmp = lst[j];
            lst[j] = lst[i];
            lst[i] = tmp;
        }
        return lst;
    }
```

so that you could generate your shuffled list with

```
var shuffled = notizen.Shuffle();
```

Comment: It shoudln't be hard to figure out what's the code if you don't want to use an extension method.

Comment: from a quick check, yes, it's the same, you just have to use rand.Next(0, i + 1); instead of the one you added since Next excludes the max value