# Random number generator with no more than 2 duplicates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have code that randomly selects 15 sprites from 51 sprites. It can generate 2 duplicated sprites (this is acceptable for me) but I want to avoid 3 duplicated values. How can I prevent that?

My code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    int arrIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, tasSprites.Length);
    tasSprite = tasSprites[arrIndex];
    tasName = tasSprite.name;
    taslar.Add(Int32.Parse(tasName));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried checking if each generated index already appears twice in `taslar` and if so, generating another one?

```
while (taslar.Count < 16)
{
    int arrIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, tasSprites.Length);
    tasSprite = tasSprites[arrIndex];
    tasName = tasSprite.name;
    int value = Int32.Parse(tasName);
    if (taslar.Count(t => t == value) < 2)
    {
        taslar.Add(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
int[] indexesCount = new int[tasSprites.Length];

while (taslar.Count < 16)
{
    int arrIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, tasSprites.Length);

    if (indexesCount[arrIndex] == 2)
    {
        continue;
    }

    indexesCount[arrIndex]++;

    tasSprite = tasSprites[arrIndex];
    tasName = tasSprite.name;
    taslar.Add(Int32.Parse(tasName));
}
```

Note that this solution is "good" while `tasSprites.Length` is relatively small. We are creating a temporary array of size `tasSprites.Length` to see which numbers have already been used.

Answer (score 1):

- Generate an array with each of your sprites in twice
- Select 15 values from the array using e.g. a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553282/randomize-liststring-without-duplicates)

This will save you the chance of possibly repeatedly generating values that have already been used twice.

Comment: that's a changed requirement to OPs question - he wants to allow duplicates

Comment: The OP *did* specify "each sprite twice"

Comment: @Dr.Snail `It can generate 2 duplicated sprites (this is acceptable for me)` - I've interpreted this as *each sprite can appear up to twice*.